# inapp purchase for iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I need to implement inapp purchase for an app and i am doing 1st time inapp purchase.
I am not getting which code i need to put to get my work done.
I have put code as below.
Do i need to add request of product list and response?

```
- (IBAction)Upgrade:(id)sender {
    /* Store Kit Framework Payment Object with Specified Product Identifier -By Parth */

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.dev.InAppTry"];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}


/* Updated Transactions Once Purchase is done. This is where we enable or disable some app */
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

        NSLog(@"transactions  : %@",transactions);

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                //[self downloadFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iphonedevnation.com/tutorials/ForestGreen.mp3"]];
                flgCheck = 1;
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                lblremovead.enabled = YES;
                adSwitch.enabled = YES;
                //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"IN_APP_PURCHASE"];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"An error encounterd");
                }

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this link it may be useful to you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015744/iphone-in-app-purchase-app-registration-with-itunes-steps-for-testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following links can provide you with the basic information you need to know about In-App purchasing

[Link 1](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

[Link 2](http://nixsolutions.com/blog/development/iphone/in-app-purchase-tutorial/)

[Link 3](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/)

Hope it helps