# How to add In App purchase for for premium verision of application?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Hi can any body tell me how to add the feature of In App purchase premium version of application. Infect i want to sale my application free but some of the features will not be available in free app. To unlock all the features user will have to purchase a premium version of app. So can anybody guide me how to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate : [inapp purchase for iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785783/inapp-purchase-for-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Google search would have been pretty successful on this.

I have already implemented InApp purchase facility by considering both :

- [this tutorial](http://nixsolutions.com/blog/development/iphone/in-app-purchase-tutorial/)
- [and dedicated Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/AddingaStoretoYourApplication/AddingaStoretoYourApplication.html)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a limited functionality free version and a full paid version = 2 applications in the app store.

Alternatively you can create a free app with options for user to purchase / unlock certain areas of functionality. A simple google search turns up: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/