# iOS in-app purchase's receipt string explained

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, uniqueidentifier, receipt

I try to understand the receipt information obtained from iTunes server, but could not find relevant documentation.

Particularly, what's the difference among `unique_identifier`, `unique_vendor_identifier`, `original_transaction_id` (which is claimed, in a WWDC'12 session, to be a de facto customer id) and `[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]`?

```
{"receipt":
    {"original_purchase_date_pst":"...",        
     "purchase_date_ms":"...", 
     "unique_identifier":"...", 
     "original_transaction_id":"...", 
     "bvrs":"...", 
     "transaction_id":"...", 
     "quantity":"...", 
     "unique_vendor_identifier":"...", 
     "item_id":"...", 
     "product_id":"...", 
     "purchase_date":"...", 
     "original_purchase_date":"...", 
     "purchase_date_pst":"...", 
     "bid":"...", 
     "original_purchase_date_ms":"..."},  
"status":0}`
```

I wish to store this receipt information on my server to track subscription validity. So it is better to know which id I should use as a surrogate for user identity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your software should only rely on the fields that Apple describes in their documentation. They could remove unique_identifier or unique_vendor_identifier, change their meaning, or change their values  at any time without telling you about it.

You should follow Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW5) in regard to verifying subscription receipts using Apple's servers before your server transmits the sbuscription content to the device.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your suggestion. It makes a lot of sense. (I will seek a second opinion for a while before accepting yours as the answer.)

Comment: That's fine. Someone else may do it the way you want to do it and can offer their advice, or perhaps have more specific suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

In [Verifying Store Receipts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html) there is a nice table that gives the fields that seemingly one can rely on in a receipt. That specific method does rely on connecting with Apple's server. Another description (though less readable) of the receipt fields is in [Receipt Fields](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW12).